# How can I use the fundamental theorem of calculus in composite functions

Tags: calculus

My question is really simple.

Suppose the function $\theta(x)$ is smooth and well-defined.

If

> $$f(x)=\int \cos \theta(x)dx$$

Where $\theta(x)=\int g(x)dx$.

I couldn't use the Fundamental theorem  of calculus directly and I want to know what we can say about the derivative $f'(x)$ of $f(x)$ in terms of $g(x)$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can still say that $f'(x) = \cos(\theta(x))$, regardless of whether $\theta$ itself is an integral/antiderivative.

Note, by the way, that usually an integral sign $\int$ without bounds suggests that $f$ is an antiderivative, which means that $f'(x) = \cos(\theta(x))$ is true by *definition*; the fundamental theorem of calculus relates the antiderivative to the integral, and thus allows you to relate $\int \cos(\theta(x))\,\mathrm dx$ with $\int_a^x \cos(\theta(y))\,\mathrm dy$ (for some fixed $a$).